# Updating view from setState() not triggering rerender when expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Answer:**
I'm a bonehead. This is way late but don't want to leave a thread unanswered and especially since my initial answer was **wrong**. I needed to reference the *new* props I was getting, not **this.props**. As usual the answer was in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). I updated my own answer below to reflect this.

**Edit 1:**
My first fiddle did not fully show my issue so I've [updated it](https://jsfiddle.net/adrian_r/etrLo7p0/) to demonstrate better. For some reason when I call my *setState()* I believe the first pass through it is undefined even though its given a value, yet on subsequent passes it works as expected. It seems like my initial *setState()* call is not triggering a rerender but all others are.

A bit different to the usual "setState not updating view" question as *setState()* IS updating my view and with the correct value. Just not when I expect it to. Basically I am triggering a setState() event should rerender my child component with new props which I believe should trigger the childs components componentWillReceiveProps lifecyle event, which will then call *setState()* within the child component and update its view. The issue is while it does update the view, it seems to do it a cycle behind when expected. In my MVP I call *setState()* at 2 seconds yet it updates the view at 4 seconds. I haven't been able to determine which part is the bad logic though.

Here is my [jsFiddle MVP](https://jsfiddle.net/adrian_r/etrLo7p0/). Thanks for any suggestions.

Code:

```
class TaskBody extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({
      activeTask: this.props.activeTask
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
    < h4 > {
        this.state.activeTask ? this.state.activeTask : 'Task Title'
      } < /h4>
  < /div > ;
}
}

class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTask: '',
      counter: 1
    };
    this.updateActive = this.updateActive.bind(this);
  }
  updateActive(task) {
    this.setState({
      activeTask: task
    });
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(self.state.counter === 4){
            clearInterval(self.clickInterval);
            return clearInterval(self.countInterval);
        }
        self.setState({ counter: self.state.counter + 1 });
    }, 1000);
    // imagine this was the click event, it should rerender the view
    // instantaneously at 2 seconds because I called setState() right?
    // which is supposed to trigger a re-render and then TaskBody should
    // receive new props triggering it to setState() on its activeTask,
    // which should update the view?
    self.clickInterval = setInterval(function(){
        self.setState({ activeTask: 'took double the time it should' });
    }, 2000);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
        < TaskBody activeTask = {
        this.state.activeTask
      }/> 
      <div>{this.state.counter}</div>
      </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.querySelector('#body'));
```

Comment: It seems like this post from Facebook about componentWillReceiveProps could be relevant: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html

Answer (score 0):

The

```
self.setState({ activeTask: 'took double the time it should' });
```

is never actually called.

Here's why:

Your logic is located within the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. If you read [the documentation of `componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), you'll see that it clearly states:

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs.

So, when `componentDidMount` gets called in your app, you're first checking the counter and calling a `setState` there. That alone will trigger a new render. This means that your second code block within `componentDidMount` is going to have no effect because while you set the method, it's never going to get called anywhere.

Comment: ah your right. I don't think my example covered my scenario correctly. I've updated my fiddle to better reflect the issue. my setState() is getting called because it is causing a rerender multiple times, yet for some reason it misses the first pass through. or maybe im dumb...

Answer (score 0):

In my old answer, I was using a setTimeout() as a hack to get the results I wanted. Basically, if I wrapped my setState in a timeout it would set the state with the new props, but if I did not it would still reference the old props. Fortunately, this is already handled in react as componentWillReceiveProps already receives a newProps argument by default.

This:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
        self.setState({activeTask: self.props.activeTask});
      },0);
}
```

becomes

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
      var self = this;
      self.setState({activeTask: newProps.activeTask});
}
```